# Does this count as a proper derivation of the formula for work and kinetic energy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, kinematics, work

$v_{av}$ = average velocity,
$d$= distance,
$a$ = acceleration,
$m$ = mass

Given:
$$v_{av}*t=d$$
$$t=\frac{v_f-v_i}{a}$$
$$v_{av}=\frac{v_f+v_i}{2}$$

Then:
$$\frac{v_f+v_i}{2}*\frac{v_f-v_i}{a}=d$$
$$\frac{v_f^2-v_i^2}{2a}=d$$
$$\frac12(v_f^2-v_i^2)=ad$$
multiply by m to adjust for the amount of mass that accelerated
$$\frac12m(v_f^2-v_i^2)=mad$$

And if not, why is this not proper as a derivation of kinetic energy and work? What's incorrect, conceptually, about my process?

Comment: This has much in common with the usual algebra-based approach, my only critique would be that the focus is on symbol manipulation instead of talking about the meaning of what you're doing (and that's a style issue rather than something fundamental). "Serious" treatments use calculus, because it makes it explicit that you don't need periods of constant acceleration, but again that's a nitpick.

Comment: @dmckee Would it be fine if I post a derivation more focused on the meaning of the symbols then? I'd rather not make a separate thread.

Comment: This derivation works where $F$ is constant over the path, then $W=\int_{path}Fds=F\Delta s$ but not for the general case where $F$ (and $a$) are not constant.

Comment: @Gert: That's mostly what dmckee was hinting at with the "usual algebra-based approach"

Answer (score 0):

This is not a proper derivation.
At a fundamental level, there are at least three important points that are not taken into account by this approach:

1. as you consider a second mass point, it is somewhat difficult to adjust (in a non-arbitrary way) the derivation to obtain the correct energy term related to the angular momentum and/or rigid body rotation (think about a satellite in orbit around a planet, for example);
2. this approach, as it is, cannot drive you to the corret answer if you have a force which act orthogonally to the direction of motion of mass; basically, it misses the point of vector calculus: would you use a scalar product, a vector product, or a combination of the two, and why? Without any further hypotesis, it is impossible to decide (think about a mass in uniform, circular motion; or a charge in motion in magnetic field);
3. it is neglecting one of the most important issues: the fact that the position, velocities and potentials are in the most general case functions of time. Energy is not about average quantities. Try to write down the energy associated with a falling mass in a uniform gravitational field, derive it with respect to time, and see what happens... If you do the same using your approach, you will end up with meaningless results.

Comment: I think this is a harsh answer. As mentioned by @dmckee, it is appropriate for an **algebra based approach**. It only deals with the **one** dimensional case with constant acceleration, using algebra instead of calculus.

Comment: @Frédéric: I didn't mean to be rude, I am sorry if it seemed like that. The point I make is not about dimensionality (a uniform circular motion is a one-dimentional problem). What I wanted to say is, that the fact of using an algebra-based approach can lead to wrong results, even for 1-d problem, if the proper assumptions are not made. In any case, I am sorry again if the passed message was a different one, and thank you for spotting it out.